# VS 2017 WebCompiler doesn't compile .jsx files on save

Tags: javascript, reactjs, visual-studio-2017, web-compiler

I've recently migrated to MS Visual Studio 2017 Enterprise and installed the Web Compiler plugin. However, the compile-on-save functionality doesn't work which is very annoying. I saw a couple of [issues on GitHub](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/277) about other people having the same problem, but with no resolutions. Can someone suggest a way to bypass this bug?

**UPDATE**

Follow this issue if you are looking for further info: [click here](https://github.com/madskristensen/WebCompiler/issues/299)